# jQuery Button Press Interfering with PHP if(isset)?

Tags: php, jquery

I have two functions that need to work when a button is pressed, but (I think)the problem is one is jQuery and the other is PHP (I can't change that part). This is what my code looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clicker").click(function(){
          alert ("Button Was Clicked!");
        });
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action = "page_name.php">
<input id="clicker" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>
<?php
    $msg = "Not Clicked!";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $msg = "Clicked!";
    }
?>
<p> <?php echo $msg; ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, the PHP is not working, but the jQuery is. Could someone tell me what I need to change and why?
Thanks!

Comment: use a button instead of an input. and this `<?php echo $msg; ?>` should be giving you an undefined variable notice

Comment: What you need is a form and a button. Head over to the basic html tutorials (google is your friend) and go to the part where it tells you about forms.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I tried that, but it still didn't work...

Comment: Repeat after me: "PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side (sorta')".

Comment: Can you explain what part that you want is not working is it that your JavaScript is not showing alert...??

Comment: ok there's nothing wrong with your code. you sure that's a `.php` file? you running this under your own PC or hosted? use forms too. you didn't even tell us what result you're looking to get. Not working doesn't tell us much.

Comment: here http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: *"PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side (sorta')", Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Very nice Ralph* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Thanks Sam* - @JayBlanchard I learn fast.

Comment: **RULE**: forms default to GET if a method is omitted. There, solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `form` to submit `POST` request.

Just change this:

```
<input id="clicker" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

with

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <button id="clicker" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is better to leave the action out altogether than have it as an empty string...that way it still self-references on submit and also is valid html. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-fs-action

Answer (score 0):

Put this under your jquery script

```
$("#clicker").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault() ; alert ("Button Was Clicked!");
```

Comment: there is no need to use: `e.preventDefault()` as OP is not using submit in jquery.

Comment: Look at the input @RonakPatel - it *is* a submit.

Comment: Yes that's quite obvious because by using e.preventDefault  we are actually stopping it for submitting so if isset submit won't execute..

Comment: What you want is first show an alert and than get a message through php as well???